# Is the Docker image `selenium/standalone-firefox:3.4.0-chromium` designed to include both Firefox and Chrome drivers?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

Is the Docker image `selenium/standalone-firefox:3.4.0-chromium` designed to include both Firefox and Chrome drivers?

Right now I have this Dockerfile to build a selenium server:

```
FROM selenium/standalone-firefox:3.4.0-chromium
USER root
ENV NODE_ENV test
RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/cdt-tests/csv-data
COPY ./csv-data /usr/local/cdt-tests/csv-data
USER seluser
```

and it works with Firefox, but I am getting this Chrome-related error:

```
[20:14:36] I/testLogger - [chrome #11] PID: 15
[chrome #11] Specs: /usr/local/cdt-tests/test/e2e/by-roles/itso/home-page/home-page-spec.js
[chrome #11] 
[chrome #11] (node:15) [DEP0022] DeprecationWarning: os.tmpDir() is deprecated. Use os.tmpdir() instead.
[chrome #11] selenium host: cdt-selenium.cdt-net
[chrome #11] cdt server host: cdt-server.cdt-net
[chrome #11] cdt server port: 3040
[chrome #11] [20:14:35] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://cdt-selenium.cdt-net:4444/wd/hub
[chrome #11] 
[chrome #11] /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546
[chrome #11]         throw new ctor(message);
[chrome #11]               ^
[chrome #11] WebDriverError: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
[chrome #11]     at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
[chrome #11]     at parseHttpResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
[chrome #11]     at doSend.then.response (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
[chrome #11]     at <anonymous>
[chrome #11]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
[chrome #11] From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
[chrome #11]     at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
[chrome #11]     at Function.createSession (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
[chrome #11]     at createDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
[chrome #11]     at Builder.build (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
[chrome #11]     at Hosted.getNewDriver (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
[chrome #11]     at Runner.createBrowser (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
[chrome #11]     at q.then.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
[chrome #11]     at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
[chrome #11]     at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
[chrome #11]     at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
```

so my only guess is that Docker image is actually not designed to include a Google Chrome Selenium driver? Then why does it have "chromium" in the image name? Confused.

Answer (score 1):

No. "chromium" in this case is a version designator. Check out https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-firefox/tags/ and you'll see bismuth, antimony, astatine, copper. This project uses elements as version or build identifiers apparently.

Comment: ughhh yeah I was reading about how Firefox was toying with using Chromium (the open source version of Chrome?) how confusing. Maybe you can answer this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47145325/create-dockerfile-that-includes-firefox-and-chrome-drivers-for-selenium