# Create Dockerfile that includes Firefox and Chrome drivers for Selenium

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have the following Dockerfile which will build a Selenium server

```
FROM selenium/standalone-firefox:3.4.0-chromium
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome

USER root
ENV NODE_ENV test

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/cdt-tests/csv-data
COPY ./csv-data /usr/local/cdt-tests/csv-data
USER seluser
```

*obviously the two FROM statements is incorrect* => How can I create a Selenium server container that has both a Chrome driver and Firefox driver for Selenium. As far as I can tell, the `selenium/standalone-firefox:3.4.0-chromium` image only works for Firefox.

Comment: Perhaps Selenium Hub has drivers for both Firefox and Chrome?   tjmaher.com/2016/07/setting-up-selenium-grid-with-chrome.htm‌​l

Comment: Can you define what you want in the question. Why are you trying to build a single image?  Hub is the normal way to present a single endpoint for multiple browsers.

Comment: @Matt yep, sounds like it, I just realized what Selenium Hub was for after I asked the question, if you write an answer explaining this, I will upvote, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no inheritance type setup for Dockerfiles like you are suggesting.

To implement a combined build you would need find the common `FROM` ancestor of the `standalone-firefox` and `standalone-chrome`, which is `selenium/node-base` and create your own Docker file to reapply all the build steps that `selenium/standalone-chrome` applies. Then keep it in sync whenever Selenium update their builds.

Dockerfile Hierarchy:

```
                selenium/node-base
                /               \
selenium/node-chrome          selenium/node-firefox
               |                 |
selenium/standalone-chrome    selenium/standalone-firefox
```

The problem is these builds have been designed to be seperate, so there is significant overlap in the variables and settings that the images use that you would also need to unpick in your custom build to control and run both chrome and firefox at the same time. You will probably end up having to do everything from scratch.

#### Selenium Grid

Running individual [Selenium grid](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2) node's behind a [grid hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/hub/) is the standard way to do multi browser testing from a single endpoint. You can run [Firefox](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-firefox/), [Chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome/) or [Phantom JS](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-phantomjs/) nodes in Docker or connect [standard nodes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2#configuring-the-nodes-by-command-line) from anywhere else.

#### Poor mans grid

You can always run a container for Chrome and Firefox on seperate ports and point the same test suite at a different port if setting up a Grid is a lot of work for the simple case of running some tests against each browser.

Comment: The node ones won't work as standalone images without some help. They're for use in a grid.

Comment: @PaulHicks Which part did you read as suggesting that?  The standalone images replace the entry point on the `node` images to get working.  I was trying to illustrate that setup with the hierarchy.

Comment: Does Selenium Hub do what I want? http://www.tjmaher.com/2016/07/setting-up-selenium-grid-with-chrome.html

Comment: Yep sorry @Matt. Once you put in the ascii lines I understood better. I thought it was a list of images, not a hierarchy.

Comment: @PaulHicks Cool, thanks. My ascii art skillz are lacking.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot merge two docker files likes that. You can use one as a base for your docker file, then copy the important bits from the other into your one.

However you shouldn't really need to. There are images out there with [multiple browsers and drivers included](https://hub.docker.com/r/vvoyer/docker-selenium-firefox-chrome/). Or better, you could set up a grid with the [hub image](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/hub/) and [some](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-firefox/) [driver](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/node-chrome/) images.

You might even consider a library such as [Serenity](http://www.thucydides.info/) or a product such as [Katalon](https://www.katalon.com/), both of which do it all for you.  There is even a [Katalon docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/katalonstudio/katalon-studio/) designed for use in CI: it's command-line + headless only, but that's all you need for most of your CI-driven regression testing.

Comment: Does Selenium Hub do what I want? tjmaher.com/2016/07/setting-up-selenium-grid-with-chrome.htm‌​l

Comment: Grid allows you to provide as many browsers as you like, of whatever type you like, potentially distributed across as many machines as you like. Then your client (test code) chooses what kind of machine/browser it wants to run on and asks the hub to direct all the jotw requests to the right place. So instead of having your tests know about two drivers (firefox and chrome), it knows about only one (remote) and includes a request for firefox or chrome when connecting to the driver.